# How can I find all the unique Node in my XML by using XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Hi I am new in xslt transformation. I need to find all the unique node (need to discard the node where all the fields inside the node is same with other node) from my input xml

My Input xml is

```
<ns7:newElement xmlns:ns7="http://TargetNamespace.com/NewElement">
<ns7:LFULL-REC>
    <ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>56201</ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>
    <ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>22</ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>
    <ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>1</ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>
    <ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>42</ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>
</ns7:LFULL-REC>
<ns7:LFULL-REC>
    <ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>7643</ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>
    <ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>20</ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>
    <ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>1</ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>
    <ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>42</ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>
</ns7:LFULL-REC>
<ns7:LFULL-REC>
    <ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>56201</ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>
    <ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>22</ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>
    <ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>1</ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>
    <ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>42</ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>
</ns7:LFULL-REC></ns7:newElement>
```

I want Unique Node in output as

```
<ns7:newElement xmlns:ns7="http://TargetNamespace.com/NewElement">
<ns7:LFULL-REC>
    <ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>56201</ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>
    <ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>22</ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>
    <ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>1</ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>
    <ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>42</ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>
</ns7:LFULL-REC>
<ns7:LFULL-REC>
    <ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>7643</ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>
    <ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>20</ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>
    <ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>1</ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>
    <ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>42</ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>
</ns7:LFULL-REC></ns7:newElement>
```

How Can I achieve that using xslt 1.0 . I can not use xslt 2.0.

Comment: What is meant with '*the unique node*'? Do you want to discard the duplicate `<ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>`? Which one would like to keep? The first one? Did you try something?

Comment: @potame He does say _"(need to discard the node where all the fields inside the node is same with other node)"_. Though "field" has no meaning in XML and can mean children, elements, attributes, comments...

Comment: Please show what you've got so far. SO is not about doing your work for you, but we like to help you with your programming problem. Show the XSLT. Have a look at [mcve] and [ask] if you need help setting it up.

Comment: Also, the XML you show is totally not valid, just about every line has a different opening tag than a closing tag. As written, this cannot be used for any XML task, I'm afraid. Please update.

Comment: Shuvra, thanks for your edit, but it is still not valid (suggestion: use an XML editor, there are many free available, it'll save you soooo much time), and you didn't (yet) answer the other questions, which makes it very hard for us to help you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you fix your question with proper input, something along the following lines will work. You'll need to extend it to whatever you consider "fields".

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:e="http://TargetNamespace.com/NewElement"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <!-- your current code here, the part you didn't show, so you'll need 
         to adjust the rest to match whatever structure you already have -->

    <xsl:key match="e:LFULL-REC" name="dupe" use="concat(e:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID, '-', e:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT)" />

    <xsl:template match="e:LFULL-REC[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('dupe', concat(e:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID, '-', e:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT)))]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() |@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="e:LFULL-REC" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This uses [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), named after the first person that came up with this idea. Google it, there are plenty tutorials and even a [Wikipedia article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT/Muenchian_grouping).

Answer (score 0):

The functx:distinct-deep function compares nodes based on whether they are deep-equal, then returns only the first node with each distinct value.You can use below code.

```
functx:distinct-deep($in-xml//ns7:LFULL-REC)
```

[refer this](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_distinct-deep.html)

Comment: I assume you mean [functx:distinct-deep](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_distinct-deep.html), which is an XSLT 2.0 function, using `xsl:function`, and this user wants XSLT 1.0...

Comment: Hi @Abel I have modified the xml with matching start and end tag

Comment: I Tried to use below code  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ns7="http://TargetNamespace.com/NewElement">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="LfullVal" match="ns7:LFULL-REC" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <ns7:newElement>
  
   <xsl:copy-of select=
    "*/*/ns7:LFULL-REC[generate-id()
             =
              generate-id(key('LfullVal', .)[1])
              ]
    "/>  
  

   
    </ns7:newElement>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>      It does not return any

Comment: @Shuvra, why are you commenting here and not under the relevant answer? Also, as you can see, it is useless to copy complete code here, it is unreadable. What I _can_ see is that you changed the coede in such a way that it is likely not working. Please, please, please, update your question (answer all questions in the comments) as it is really hard to help you this way, and if you test my code, test it first as-is against your example code as-is (it will work).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to transform it successfully

My Input xml was

```
    <ns7:newElement xmlns:ns7="http://TargetNamespace.com/NewElement">
<ns7:LFULL-REC>
    <ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>56201</ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>
    <ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>22</ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>
    <ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>1</ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>
    <ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>42</ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>
</ns7:LFULL-REC>
<ns7:LFULL-REC>
    <ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>7643</ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>
    <ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>20</ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>
    <ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>1</ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>
    <ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>42</ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>
</ns7:LFULL-REC>
<ns7:LFULL-REC>
    <ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>56201</ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>
    <ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>22</ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>
    <ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>1</ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>
    <ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>42</ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>
</ns7:LFULL-REC></ns7:newElement>
```

My Updated xslt is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:ns7="http://TargetNamespace.com/NewElement">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key match="ns7:LFULL-REC" name="dupe" use="concat(ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID, '-', ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT,'-',ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO,'-',ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT)" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ns7:newElement>
            <xsl:for-each select="ns7:newElement/ns7:LFULL-REC[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('dupe', concat(ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID, '-', ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT,'-',ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO,'-',ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT)))]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/> 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ns7:newElement>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output xml is

```
    <ns7:newElement xmlns:ns7="http://TargetNamespace.com/NewElement">
<ns7:LFULL-REC>
    <ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>56201</ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>
    <ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>22</ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>
    <ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>1</ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>
    <ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>42</ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>
</ns7:LFULL-REC>
<ns7:LFULL-REC>
    <ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>7643</ns7:MESSAGE-GROUP-ID>
    <ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>20</ns7:FULL-TOTAL-MESSAGE-CNT>
    <ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>1</ns7:FULL-MESSAGE-SERIAL-NO>
    <ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>42</ns7:FULL-TRANSMITED-REC-CNT>
</ns7:LFULL-REC></ns7:newElement>
```

thanks @Abel for the valuable Input

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Note that you do not have to use the same namespace prefix (see my example), unless you like `ns7` ;). This was precisely the direction I wated to point you to. Though you chose for `xsl:for-each`, which is generally not necessary. While you learn more about XSLT, you'll find that using `xsl:apply-templates` and writing matching `xsl:template` is (most of the time) far easier than for-each.